# jquery buttons - hidden divs get refreshed or loaded once they are shown

Tags: jquery

I have a series of buttons which show and hide divs. I would like to only load the data from the hidden div once the button is pressed. So basically all hidden divs would get refreshed or loaded once they are shown.

Does anybody know how to do this?

```
<button class="menubutton" id="1">1</button>
<button class="menubutton" id="2">2</button>
<button class="menubutton" id="3">3</button>
<button class="menubutton" id="4">4</button>


<div id="1" style="display:none;">
DATA
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none;">
DATA
</div>

<div id="3" style="display:none;">
DATA
</div>

<div id="4" style="display:none;">
DATA
</div>

$("#1").button().click(function() {
$('#1').show();
$('#2').hide();
$('#3').hide();
$('#4').hide();
});

etc
```

Comment: each div has some db queries and datatables (not all datatables are serverside processing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the content with AJAX: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

So you do something like this:

```
$('.menuButton').click(function()) {
    $('.menuButton').hide();
    if ($(this).html() == '') {
        $.get('somepage.html', function(data) {
            $(this).html(data);
        });
    }
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: Sounds promising as at the moment i am using include_once, so theoretically ill just need to replace include once with this click function

Comment: If you need to pass an ID to the DB for the content, just grab the button's ID and pass it to the handler page with the AJAX call as a query param, e..g. $.get('somepage.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id')). If you need more options look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, my .js works but not getting any data. how can i pass global variables through the .get?

Comment: Try hard coding the variables into the query string first to debug, when you get that working you can extend it.

What exactly do you mean by 'passing global variables' ?

Comment: its ok i managed --------- <div id="approved_list" style="display:none;" class="<?php echo $USER->id; ?>"> ---------    $.get('department_waiting_approval.php?userid='+$('#department_waiting_approval_list').attr('class'), function(data) {
    $("#department_waiting_approval_list").html(data);});